# CSS animations vs jQuery Animation vs using a gif

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-transforms, animated-gif

I have a site where several elements need to be animated (pngs or jpgs) and I've been using either jquery animate or css transforms/transitions to get them working but I am wondering if using a gif would be better performance wise. Is there a benefit to using one of these methods over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Animated gifs are probably going to be your most efficient because it is a self contained graphic file.  That said, if it is a vector based animation, a JS solution could be a lot more lightweight and therefore load faster.

Lastly, Gifs have a lower color depth than jpg or png so if image quality is major a concern, you'll want to weigh that in as well.